# Simple PHP Auth Class feedback

Tags: php, design-patterns, object-oriented

this is a basic PHP auth class I've put together for use with simple sites I do from time to time which don't warrant using a framework. I'm wondering if i'm separating out responsibilities all that well, even at this early stage! For example, I'm not sure where I should be filtering user input with mysql_real_escape_string, and I don't know if I should be passing the DB into the constructor, but then I need it to be able to run my auth check.

Anyway, any pointers would be great thanks!

```
class Auth {

    protected $db;

    /**
     * Auth::__construct()
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public function __construct($db = null)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    /**
     * Auth::login()
     * 
     * @param mixed $username
     * @param mixed $password
     * @return
     */
    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username, password 
                                    FROM users 
                                    WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'
                                    AND password = '".self::crypt_pass(mysql_real_escape_string($password))."'
                                  ");

        $result = $this->db->fetch_array($query);

        if (count($result) == 0)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            //set session variable 
            Session::instance()->set('logged_in', TRUE);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Auth::logout()
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        //set session variable 
        return Session::instance()->delete('logged_in');
    }

    private function crypt_pass($pass)
    {
        if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1)
        {
            $salt = SHA1('acssalty457');
            $blowfish_salt = "\$2a\$07\$".substr($salt, 0, CRYPT_SALT_LENGTH);
            return crypt($pass, $blowfish_salt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This part doesn't make sense to me:

```
private function crypt_pass($pass)
{
    if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1)
    {
        $salt = SHA1('acssalty457');
        $blowfish_salt = "\$2a\$07\$".substr($salt, 0, CRYPT_SALT_LENGTH);
        return crypt($pass, $blowfish_salt);
    }
}
```

Functions that only return on condition are a bad idea. You should return something anyway, even if it's false. Now for the specific problem, what if `CRYPT_BLOWFISH != 1`? It's ok to want to use blowfist, but why cripple the library for everyone else? You could rewrite as:

```
private function crypt_pass($pass) {
    $salt = "acssalty457";

    if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1) {
        $blowfish_salt = "\$2a\$07\$" . substr($salt, 0, CRYPT_SALT_LENGTH);
        return crypt($pass, $blowfish_salt);
    }

    return sha1($pass . $salt);        
}
```

Notice that I don't hash the salt? That's because security wise that's useless. You can ask around at [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) for more. If you want to make the sha1 crypted pass a little bit harder you could do something weird like:

```
return sha1(strrev($salt) . $pass . $salt);
```

I'm using `sha1` as an example of a natively included function, you can use any [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) algorithm you like.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of php they implemented this in, but you don't need to use the `__construct`, you can use `Auth` instead like many other OOP langs.

You should check if `$this->db` is `null` before you do any `sql` work, otherwise `login` will fail with errors when used.

Another thing you should look into is using `PDO` (or anything that supports **prepared statements**). `mysql_real_escape_string` is not secure these days. 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

You should also filter the email and password using regex (`preg_match`) or the php filter function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Actually, depending on the version of PHP it is much better to use `__construct()`.  [With namespaces in 5.3.3+ the class name is not used as constructor.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)  Granted, the use case for this might be small but there is nothing wrong with the use of `__construct()` and may actually be preferred if using namespaces.

Comment: @Charles Sprayberry what's the difference mechanically? I just like to use it as it matches other langs I program it so it's just one less difference I have to remember. I didn't mean to imply there's anything wrong with using it, just pointing out it can be used and may be more readable and/or future proof.

Comment: There may not be any difference mechanically...as long as you aren't using namespaces in 5.3.3.  But, for PHP the `Auth` method in the `Auth` class used as constructor is included for backward compatibility purposes.  Using this mechanic actually appears to be *less* future proof as it changes depending on the situation, whereas `__construct()` is always seen as the class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try these blowfish wrapper functions on for size:

https://gist.github.com/1151912

They wrap the functionality, restrict it to where it's available (php 5.3), and provide the hash generation function, and a test for whether a hash is blowfish or not, making it easier to move from an earlier hash system to a newer hash system.

And yeah, skip mysql_real_escape_string and move towards parameterized queries from PDO, you'll be better off:

I just have a set of parameterized PDO wrapper functions like this:

```
query('select * from users where user_id = :user_id', array(':user_id'=>$user_id));
```

To make parameterizing queries at dead simple as possible, so that it becomes the default as opposed to a troublesome addition.